# How can I make a Python script open a certain file extension by default?

Tags: windows, command-line, python

I'm making an app programmed with Python, and I need it to be the default program that opens .adv file extensions.

I looked online for answers and I found out I need a .bat file (batch file) to set the Python app as the default program that opens .adv files. I also found that I need to write something like python C:\Path\To\Script\script.py, and when I tried that, it did not work.

I also found many solution for MacOS and other Apple's OS' but nothing for windows. I also found some people saying to convert the .py into .exe but the steps provided did not work.

I'm looking for a all-in-one solution which has clear steps on how to set a Python script as the default opener for the .adv file extension on any computer that installed the app (meaning Windows automatically recognises the app as the default opener). This may not be even possible without turning the .py file into a .exe, but I want the simplest solution.

Users on Stack Overflow told me to post this question here since it is not directly connected with programming.

Answer (score 0):

The script should be:

```
import sys     
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
           #Do whatever operation you want here
```

also, the bat file should be

```
python "C:\Your\Path\To\Script" %*
```

So, what happens is when you assign the bat file as the default handler for the file type, the bat file will run the python script.Now, the `%*` in the bat files means all arguments are to given to the python script.

Now,coming to the script part,`sys.argv` returns you a list of arguments that was given by the `.bat` file. Now the sys.argv[1] (i.e. is the second element of the list) refers to the path of the `.adv` file you wanna open.Thus, the file gets opened for you....
Hope it helps!!